# Html table values not getting from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table like below.I'm going to access that values from jquery.But there's a problem

### My HTML

```
                        <table class="table" id="examtbl">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Ex No</th>
                                <th>Result</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <tr id="7500">
                                    <td id="examNo">
                                        <input class="form-control col-md-3 examNo" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="7500" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="form-control col-md-3"  type="text" value="76" />
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr id="7600">
                                    <td id="examNo">
                                        <input class="form-control col-md-3 examNo" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="7600" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input class="form-control col-md-3"  type="text" value="66" />
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
```

### My Script

```
 $("#examtbl > tbody > tr").each(function () {
       $(this).find('td').find("input").each(function () {
            alert($(".examNo").val()); < -- It hits3 times but everytime it shows me 7500 only.
       });  

   });
```

** Could you please give me a solution to how to get those values to.

Answer (score 3):

the thing is, that you always call `$(".examNo")` ... and that means, he always looks for the first item that fits... you have to use `this` in the inner each loop :)

```js
$("#examtbl > tbody > tr").each(function () {
       $(this).find('td').find("input").each(function () {
            alert($(this).val()); 
       });  
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="examtbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ex No</th>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="7500">
            <td id="examNo">
                <input class="form-control col-md-3 examNo" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="7500" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control col-md-3"  type="text" value="76" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="7600">
            <td id="examNo">
                <input class="form-control col-md-3 examNo" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="7600" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control col-md-3"  type="text" value="66" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#examtbl > tbody > tr").each(function () {
   $(this).find('td').find("input").each(function () {
        alert($(this).val()); 
   });  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

JS:

```
$("#examtbl > tbody > tr").each(function () {
                $(this).find('td > input').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('examNo'))
                    alert($(this).val()); //< -- It hits3 times but everytime it shows me 7500 only.
                });  

            });
```

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/0zved1ss/#&togetherjs=1kR0JKIshL)